# how to add a read more button to my blog page?

Tags: query

**HELLO!**

I am using this code to add a read more button to my blog page in 'content-page.php' file but this button adding to all of my website pages. I only want it on my blog page not on home page or any other site.

```
<?php
if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'http://localhost/wordpress/blogs/', true)){
 echo'<a href="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'http://localhost/wordpress/blogs/', true).'" class="more-link">Read more</a>';
}else{
 echo'<a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="more-link"><a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="myButton">Read more</a></a>';
}
?>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank You!

Comment: content-page.php would be for the content of *Pages*, not Posts. You need to edit the template that is used for post excerpts. What template that is depends on your theme, so you should ask the author.

Answer (score -1):

I believe Wordpress can do this natively. In the wp_editor menu toolbar is a “read more” button. Have you experimented with that?